# Significance of static and main in android

Tags: android

I will start with the simple programme of android :

```
public class MyClass extends Activity
{ 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main)
    }
}
```

My question is why don't we use `static` with `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` like in Java also why there is no `main` function in it?

Comment: because it's Android code. If you need real insight on why, you will have to ask the original Android conceptors.

Comment: Android launches your activity to handle an Intent that needs it.  The process for that is it instantiates the Activity.  It wouldn't make sense to call onCreate() on an Activity object that hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 1):

main is a Java convention for a desktop application which is built around the historical concept of an application that starts at point A (the first line of main) and goes to point B (the return from main) then stops.

An Android application is running in a very different environment.  It is very much event driven.  Rather than having main, what it has is a Looper (the android version of an event loop) The code you write is responding to events as they happen rather than turning command line parameters and files into output.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not an expert, but here goes with a longish answer. Or answers.

Answer 1: Probably, Android uses an instance method because Java is designed for instance methods and fields. I find things work better with instances than statics.

So, why does a traditional-computer program have a static “main()”?

Answer 2: Probably because when a JVM is fired up, there a no instances of anything, so the designers thought the initially invoked method should be static.

Which brings us to the distinction you were probably hunting for: why is mobile-program different to traditional-program?

Answer 3: The lifecycle of a traditional program is much simpler than a mobile app. A traditional program starts up, runs, and exits. In Java, the JVM starts and dies with it. An Android app has a much more complicated lifecycle. A JVM can survive the user entering and exiting the app many times. And an activity is very lightweight – rotate your device from landscape to portrait, and the activity is killed and a new one started. For more on the activity lifecycle, see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.

Consider a webserver. It is a long running process, which invokes application-layer code with an instance method for each request.  I’d say an Android app is about half way between the two lifecycle models: traditional program and web application request.

(I’ve made some sweeping statements here. Being accurate about details would have made an even longer post.)